# weird black bars for firefox users on my website

Tags: html, css, firefox

so ive been working on a small nodejs project and some of my user**s** recently see weird black bars on it, i have no clue what might cause them and i cannot reproduce them at all.

here is a screenshot: [image: weird black bars]

their browser version is Firefox 9.0.1

does anyone have an idea what might cause them?

update:
the problem still exists, i made one of the users turn off his javascript and he says that he still sees those black bars. i also made him install firebug and he says that he cant select the bars - only the elements underneath them. (dunno if he did it right though)

its quite strange, the only elements he sees right from the start are the ones which i positioned fixed.

Comment: I tried it in FF 9.0.1 and I don't get the bars. Have you checked the CSS?

Comment: i dont get them either, thats my problem. so i dont know what to check the css for.

Comment: Also tried in FF 9.0.1 and can't replicate. Seems like a user-specific problem to me. Try telling the user to turn off all add-ons, etc.

Comment: yeah the things is as i tried pointing out there are 2 users complaining about the same problems. they already tried viewing the page without addons and it didnt help =/

Comment: Does this link help? https://support.mozilla.org/eo/questions/715850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive been able to reproduce the bug on my laptop and found out what was causing the black bars:

- my header had an overflow hidden attribute and as soon as i removed it everything was working fine again.

but i still dont know WHY this would happen. i'm using a linear gradient as a background in my header and a heading with multiple text shadows. 
maybe this caused the bars on certain graphic cards.